# How to get rid of this space between the ion-labels?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I want to get rid of the space between the labels. I suppose it's due to the `<ion-item>`. Since the space disappears if I use `<div>`. But then the problem is that the elements aren't in a row anymore and if I apply `<ion-row>` on the buttons the somehow disappear, so I try to solve it with `<ion-item>`.

Here is my code and a picture of the problem

html.page

```
<ion-item mode="ios" class="out" lines="none" *ngSwitchCase="false">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label class="one"> 20 </ion-label><br />
      <ion-label class="two">Members</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-label class="one"> 5 </ion-label><br />
      <ion-label class="two"> Friends </ion-label>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-fab-button size="small" color="danger" class="report" slot="end">
    <ion-icon name="alert"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
  <ion-fab-button size="small" color="primary" slot="end">
    <ion-icon name="alert"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-item>
```

scss.page

```
.one {
  color: rgb(43, 42, 42);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  margin-bottom: 0% !important;
}

.two {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
  padding: 0% !important;
}
```

[image: Space between numbers and letters]

Comment: actually what you want , please anyone picture example?

Comment: @Colin you can simply use display: flex to keep the item in a row with div, i think it will help you

Comment: @Avinashjain Thx that worked but can I actually still have a spacing between the labels and the buttons-> so the buttons are on the right side of the screen and the labels on the left?

Comment: @ColinRagnarök can you please add either jsfiddel or codepen of your code so that i can see it

Comment: https://codepen.io/caturix99/pen/aboxRLp

Comment: I actually only want a spacing between the labels and the buttons -> labels start; buttons end